# xsel not outputing to file in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, xsel

I am currently learning French, and in order to streamline my study process, I would like to have a script that allows me to look up words on Wiktionary and keep a record of my searches for later review.

After some trial and error, I hacked together a bash script that launched the Wiktionary page for my text selection and saved the selection, and the date of the selection, to a text file.

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox 'https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/'$(xsel)'#French'
echo $(xsel)$(date +": %Y-%m-%d (%a)") >> fr/word-list.txt
```

The first dozen times I used the script it worked as desired. However, for some reason, the second line of the script is no longer fully working. The date is still outputted to the file but not the xsel text selection. The first line below is expected output; the second line is an example of the output I am currently getting.

```
enterrement: 2023-06-18 (Sun)
: 2023-06-18 (Sun)
```

I'm sure my noob script could be improved but the problem seems to be with xsel itself as it is not working consistently when I run it by itself. Sometimes it is returning a blank output including when I use `xsel -o`, `xsel -ob`, and `xsel -op`.

Confusingly, the first line of the script, which also relies on xsel, *is* working consistently.

Comment: You can try `xclip -o -selection clipboard` insted of `xsel`.

Comment: Do you think xclip is better suited for what I want my script to do or are you suggesting this simply as way to troubleshoot my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `xsel` so I have no idea what causes your problem.

But independent of that in general you should not run more external commands than necessary so the simple solution to your problem is:

```
#!/bin/bash

xsel="$(xsel)"

firefox "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/${xsel}#French"
echo "$xsel$(date +': %Y-%m-%d (%a)')" >> fr/word-list.txt
```

Comment: After making the changes you suggested, the script is working as expected again. Thank you. I'm still confused that the script initially worked and about the seemingly inconsistent xsel behaviour.

Comment: I cannot help with that. You could wait for other answers or accept mine and open a new question limited to that. Something like "Why do consecutive xsel calls lead to different results?"